# Disable scroll bar in header but not in content for a web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a simple web page with header and content, it may look like

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="header">
    </div>
    <div id="content">
    </div>
</div>
```

By default, it have a scroll bar in the right, but I want to disable/freeze the scroll bar in header, but remain it in content, is it possible to do this by javascrip/jquery or css?

Thanks

BEFORE
[image]

AFTER
[image]

Comment: are you talking about the main scrollbar to the page, if so the responses given won't work. They will only work for inline scrollbars.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by giving the content a fixed height, and setting `overflow-y: scroll`.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/XLaVa/

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have to restructure your html/css:

```
<div id='wrap'>
   <div id='header'></div>
   <div id='content-outer'>
      <div id='content-inner'>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
.content-outer {
   height: 600px; /* or desired height */
   overflow-y: scroll;
}
.content-inner {
   height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add a scrollbar to the content element itself take a look at the other answers. To achieve a similar effect via the browser's scrollbar try `position:fixed` on the header:

```
#header {
    position : fixed;
    top : 0px;
    width : 100%;
    height : 30px;
    background-color:white;
}
#content{
    margin-top : 30px;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/GUeUe/

(Note: IE <=6 doesn't support `position:fixed`.)

Answer (score 0):

Set `overflow:hidden` in the CSS for the header and `overflow:scroll` for the content.

Answer (score 0):

Add these css rules:

```
#header { overflow: hidden; }
#content { overflow: auto; }
```

You will also need to cap the height of content to not overflow the page itself.